# Trying to add a Filter to a Canvas Image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

I'm Currently Trying to apply a filter or filters to a Canvas Image after its been uploaded to the page and but if they want to change filters to more blurry or to another filter it removes the image and you will have to re-upload the image. I plan on making it where there is a button to several different filters and then they click on the filter they want to apply to the image. Any Ideas on How to fix it?

Right now when you go to upload the image, it will blur it to 5px but if you want it less or more blurry for example it will remove the image. 
Thank You! In advance! Heres a Live Link of my code: 
https://jsfiddle.net/mbyvvszy/

html:

```
<canvas id="canvas" width="1000" height="500" class="playable-canvas"></canvas>


<div id="image_div">
  <h1> Choose an Image to Upload </h1>
  <input type='file' name='img' id='uploadimage' />

</div>


<div class="playable-buttons">
  <input id="edit" type="button" value="Edit" />
  <input id="reset" type="button" value="Reset" />
</div>
<textarea id="code" class="playable-code">
ctx.filter = 'blur(5px)';
</textarea>
```

Javascript :

```
var drawnImage;

function drawImage(ev) {
  console.log(ev);
  var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d'),
    img = new Image(),
    f = document.getElementById("uploadimage").files[0],
    url = window.URL || window.webkitURL,
    src = url.createObjectURL(f);
  img.src = src;
  img.onload = function() {
    drawnImage = img;
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
    url.revokeObjectURL(src);
  }
}
document.getElementById("uploadimage").addEventListener("change", drawImage, false);



var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var textarea = document.getElementById('code');
var reset = document.getElementById('reset');
var edit = document.getElementById('edit');
var code = textarea.value;

function drawCanvas() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  eval(textarea.value);
}

reset.addEventListener('click', function() {
  textarea.value = code;
  drawCanvas();
});

edit.addEventListener('click', function() {
  textarea.focus();
})

textarea.addEventListener('input', drawCanvas);
window.addEventListener('load', drawCanvas);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `drawCanvas`, you clear the canvas but never re-draw the image. Just add a call to `drawImage`.

```
function drawCanvas() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  eval(textarea.value);
  drawImage();
}
```

Comment: It looks like it still Makes the Image go away when you go to change the px of the blurr.